# Why do I get this "Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!"?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I realise this question has been answered several times already, but I could not find a solution for this specific case. 
I keep getting

> "Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.myserver.com/api/v1/123)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in
>   /home/content/d/a/v/server/html/getFile.php on line 44"

My code:

```
$id  = $_GET['id']; 
//$id = urlencode(stripslashes($id)); <- What I´ve tried. No dice.
//$id = "123";    <- hardcoding the ID solves the problem.

// Create stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Token: abc\r\n" .
              "Token-Client: xyz\r\n" 
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
// Open the file
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.myserver.com/api/v1/'.$id , false, $context);
```

My request:

```
http://myserver.com/getFile.php?id=123
```

1) urlencode makes no difference. The argument doesn´t have spaces nor special chars. I've tried stripslashes() as well.

2) If I hardcode the $id, as in `$id="123";` it works fine.

3) I´ve noticed the same error when I get the value for $id from a database, as in `$id = $row["id"];` (I didn´t include the whole code so it doesn't pollute the question).

I´ve tried every solution I could find on the Forum. Maybe someone came across this problem before?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried reading the 500 error that's being returned? Like *really* reading it?

Comment: I´m working in it right now. My godaddy plan is not recording error logs(I have no Idea why), so I have no visibility of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem using curl.

```
$url = 'http://www.myserver.com/api/v1/'.$id;

$ch = curl_init();
$header=array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Token: abc\r\n" .
              "Token-Client: xyz\r\n" 
  );

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    $file=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Worked fine, but I don´t know why I get the error using file_get_contents.